# How to query for system features/properties?

Tags: c++, c, linux, system

I want to write a program which is capable of printing out  system properties. Is this possible?

If so, with C/C++, how can one learn system features/properties?

For example, the following properties:

```
 hardware :
 Memory 3.8 gib
 ubuntu   :
 release 10.10 ( maveric )
 system status:
 available disk space 51.1 gib
 user name  :
 xxx
 processor :
 intel ... duo cpu e4600
```

The platform being Linux.

Comment: Define "system properties".  What platform are you working on?

Comment: @TOmalak Geret'kal,If there is way to do that wish in both language, can you write answers for both of them ?

Comment: @fatai: Shall we add PHP and Javascript into the mix too?

Comment: all system properties? What does that mean?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, for me, it doesn't matter. If you have an answer for all language, I will be reedit my question as "with any language, how can one learn system features?"

Comment: There are a whole ton of attributes that can be thought of as system properties. The list of devices available on the PCI bus. The list of devices currently available on the USB bus. The color of the case. The length of the traces between the CPU and memory.  The exact timing settings for each of the installed DIMMS.  The color of the wires used for the reset button. So no, there is no way to print out __ALL__ system properties. You have to pick which things are important to you and print those out.

Comment: @DAvid Heffernan, you know , memory/cpu/platform/display adapter/

Comment: that's a list of sub systems. You don't have a real question here. Please try harder to formulate one.

Comment: I give the example to show what I want, what purpose do you have ? if you want close that question, I will do, too. If you try to improve my question, feel free, you can reeditted my question.

Comment: @fatai: Just be clear about the exact list of properties you care about. As it is, your question is really vague and open-ended. For example, I really couldn't tell from your question whether or not you care about filesystems that aren't mounted, nor could I tell if a list of devices on the PCI and/or USB busses were appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Linux You can simple use the function:

```
int uname(struct utsname *buf);
```

by including the header

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
```

it returns the system information as a part of the structure:

```
struct utsname 
   {
       char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
       char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined network" */
       char release[];    /* OS release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
       char version[];    /* OS version */
       char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
       #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
       char domainname[]; /* NIS or YP domain name */
       #endif
   };
```

Well, if not all, atleast it gives you some `system properties` as you said. There should be other api available which can reveal all the information you need. You will need to check out the documentation & search around a bit for that.

**EDIT:**

Oh well, I just ripped this one off from the internet. This program shall help you run Linux commands programatically.

```
char* GetSystemOutput(char* cmd)
{
    int buff_size = 32;
    char* buff = new char[buff_size];

    char* ret = NULL;
    string str = "";

    int fd[2];
    int old_fd[3];
    pipe(fd);

    old_fd[0] = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
    old_fd[1] = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
    old_fd[2] = dup(STDERR_FILENO);

    int pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
        case 0:
               close(fd[0]);
               close(STDOUT_FILENO);
               close(STDERR_FILENO);
               dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
               dup2(fd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
               system(cmd);
               //execlp((const char*)cmd, cmd,0);
               close (fd[1]);
               exit(0);
               break;
        case -1:
               cerr << "GetSystemOutput/fork() error\n" << endl;
               exit(1);
        default:
               close(fd[1]);
               dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);

               int rc = 1;
               while (rc > 0)
               {
                   rc = read(fd[0], buff, buff_size);
                   str.append(buff, rc);
                   //memset(buff, 0, buff_size);
               }

               ret = new char [strlen((char*)str.c_str())];

               strcpy(ret, (char*)str.c_str());

               waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
               close(fd[0]);
    }

    dup2(STDIN_FILENO, old_fd[0]);
    dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, old_fd[1]);
    dup2(STDERR_FILENO, old_fd[2]);

    return ret;
}
```

Api Usage: `GetSystemOutput("/usr/bin/lsb_release -a")`

And following the commands:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo = tells you cpu info
cat /proc/meminfo = tells you memory info
lspci = tells you hardware that is attached (at least if the kernel recognizes it) 
cat /proc/ide/hda/* = tells you info of your first ide hard-drive.
```

Comment: You could have fixed the indentation.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: I thought it was readable but Well pointed out..I fixed it anyways.

Comment: Thanks :) It's setting a good example if nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

Look around in the /proc directory.  There's a lot of things that might be considered system properties, but you'll soon be able to determine which properties are of interest to you.

```
cat /proc/somedir/somefile
```

is the command you want to use to safely browse /proc.

Answer (score 0):

Every OS has an API that allows you to communicate with it.

Sadly it's not something uniform, you'll need to read search for your target OS's API.

Through the API you can usually get most of the information you need.